# How to delete subdocument using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB with the following schema:

```
const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyTitle: String,
    status: String,
    companyURL: String,
    jobTitle: String,
    jobURL: String,
    jobDescription: String,
    contactName: String,
    contactRole: String,
    contactPhone: String,
    contactEmail: String,
    tasks: [Task.schema]
})

 const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    taskItem: String,
    isCompleted: Boolean
})
```

When a user clicks a button, the job._id and task._id are sent to my server where the specific task should be deleted from the database. Currently, the route deletes the parent (job) instead of the child (task). Any ideas how to target the task instead? Thanks in advance!

app.js

```
app.delete('/tasks/:jobId/:taskId', (req, res) => {
    const jobId = req.params.jobId
    const taskId = req.params.taskId

    Job.findOneAndDelete(
        {'_id': jobId, 'tasks._id': taskId},
        function (error, doc) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(doc)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code delete the parent because Mongo remove a document which match the query. In this case, your "parent" match the query because it has a child with the given `_id`.

With query `findOneAndDelete({'_id': jobId, 'tasks._id': taskId})` you are telling mongo: "Delete one document where the `_id` is `jobId` and some `_id` into `tasks` array is `taskId`".

You have to use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in an update operation:

Something like

```
Job.updateOne(
  {"_id": jobId},
  {
    "$pull": {
      "tasks":{
        "_id": taskId
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Note that update has two objects: First one is the object to update and second one the "action" to do. In this case pull the subtask with the given `_id`.

This query tell to mongo: Search one object with the given `_id` and remove the `tasks` subdocument which `_id` is `taskId`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0YXftMMkyuR)

Answer (score 0):

Each subdocument has a deleteOne() method (see docs [removing-subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#removing-subdocs)). So in your case you can find the job first, then find the task by calling the `id()` method, and then call the `deleteOne()` method on it:

```
const job = await Job.findById(jobId);
const task = job.tasks.id(taskId);
task.deleteOne();
await job.save();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `findOneAndDelete`. You can refactor your code like this:

```
app.delete('/tasks/:jobId/:taskId', async (req, res) => {
  const jobId = req.params.jobId
  const taskId = req.params.taskId

  Job.findOneAndUpdate(
      {"_id": jobId },
      {"$pull": {"tasks": {"_id": taskId}}},
      {new:true}, 
      function (error, doc) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log(doc)
        }
      }
  );

})
```